# R installed the recharts error

Tags: r

```
> install_github("madlogos/recharts")

Downloading GitHub repo madlogos/recharts@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/madlogos/recharts/zipball/master
Installing recharts
"D:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
  INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAlSrMx/devtools26ec72ed478f/madlogos-recharts-ef72a0a"  \
  --library="D:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'recharts' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
```

> ```
> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>   there is no package called 'ggthemes'
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'recharts'
> * removing 'D:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library/recharts'
> * restoring previous 'D:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library/recharts'
> Error: Command failed (1)
> ```

How to solve the problem? I install the recharts but it doesn't have `echartr` function and only have `echart` function.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation depends on `ggthemes`, as the error message says. Install that package, plus any others that appear in similar error messages.

Comment: Thank you. After I installed the ggthemes, the recharts works!